# Windows plot area in Autocad

Tags: autocad

I've encountered a problem while plotting DWG to PDF.
I plot in A4 format, and when I'm choosing the window area to plot while I click on preview I see that the area has changed a little in the top and left sides.
My brother also uses autocad and maybe he changed something because this never happened to me before.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're having problems with printing margins.

Double check you're using the same printer/plotter that you're used to.

Also, look into the properties of the printer/plotter where you have more options to customize your margins.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! I invite you to have at read at this: [When should I post a comment and when should I post an answer?](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201/when-should-i-post-an-answer-and-when-should-i-post-a-comment/202#202).